# Bootstrap 4: How to make button and input same height in input-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using input groups of Twitter Bootstrap 4 to create a search bar.

HTML:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="<? echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="search" name="q" id="srcterm" placeholder="Search project &hellip;">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Suchen">
                <img src="/search/icons/search.svg" width="16" height="16" focusable="false" role="img">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #212529;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #ced4da;
 padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 border-radius: 0.25rem;
 transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-outline-success {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
 }
```

The grouping of both input and button works fine. But the button seems to be some px higher than the input field:

[image]

The issue is coming up on several browsers (tested on IE 11 as well as current versions of Edge, Firefox and Chrome).

As you can see above, I modified Bootstrap's original CSS regarding color, border etc. I replaced the relevant classes with the ones from the original Bootstrap CSS to see if this has any effect but to no avail.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest adding bootstrap CDN and a snippit that recreates the issue, or a Fiddle that that recreates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With this layout, the input field and the button have the same height (i tested this on codepen.io)

Probably there are third party (non Bootstrap) styles on the project that interfere with Bootstrap styles.

You need to open DevTools and see what styles are applied to the input field, button and their common parent.

Perhaps removing the checkboxes to the rules will help you understand which ones are interfering.

It is impossible to exclude problems with the picture inserted into the button, you need to look (try to disable) and its styles.